# What is wrong with the fourth character of int variable?

Tags: c

My machine is a 32-bit PC running centos system,and i used GCC to compile my C codes.
And the int variable occupy 4 bytes.So i wrote codes like this...

```
    #include "stdio.h"
    int main(){
           int a=1;
           printf("%c",*(&a+1)+65);
           printf("%c",*(&a+2)+65);
           printf("%c",*(&a+3)+65);
    }
```

I was thinking like this:
The pC is in 32-bit so the variable a shoule be stored in memory like this:

```
   &a    00000001
   &a+1  00000000
   &a+2  00000000
   &a+3  00000000
```

So i think the answer should be :AAA
But what a real got is :qA(The last one didn't print it out.)
I do feel puzzled by the result. And what's more ,if i digestion the last two printf.which is:

```
    #include "stdio.h"
    int main(){
           int a=1;
           printf("%c",*(&a+1)+65);
    }
```

Then i got what i want:A
Is anything wrong with my codes or what;s real wrong is my thinking about variable storing in memory...Please help me out of the stuff,thanks.

Comment: You should really use bit masks for this rather than pointer arithmetic.

Comment: In addition, this code is endian-dependent and non-portable.

Answer (score 3):

here, `&a` is of type `int*`, so `&a+1` points to the next int (4 bytes after). You need to convert `&a` to `char*` before : `((char *) &a) + 1`

Answer (score 1):

When you say "&a+1" that doesn't mean +1 byte, it means +1 sizeof(int).

If you cast &a to char* then your +1 will mean +1 sizeof(char). The size of char will be 1 byte.

Answer (score 0):

cast you pointer `&a` to `char *` pointer like this

```
printf("%c",*((char*)&a+1)+65);
```

`&a + 1` means that you have incremented the address of `a` with `1` * size of `a` and the size of a is 4 byte = 4 * size of char.

Casting the address of `a` to `char *` pointer wil allow to increment the address of `a` with 1 * sizeof char (=1 byte)